# NetBeans no reconoce el paquete org de GeoTools

Tags: java, netbeans, librería, ide

Estuve instalando geotools en mi aplicación de java pero NetBeans no reconoce estos paquetes:

```
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer; 
import org.geotools.map.Layer;
import org.geotools.map.MapContent;
import org.geotools.styling.SLD;
import org.geotools.styling.Style;
import org.geotools.swing.JMapFrame;
import org.geotools.swing.data.JFileDataStoreChooser;
```

Estos imports los he cogido del código inicial que propone GeoTools en su Quickstart para NetBeans. Muestro ahora que he probado con muchas releases: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas librerías están en el apartado "Librerías" de NetBeans. ¿Estoy importando mal las librerías? Decir que me he basado en la descarga manual de las librerías a través de sourceforge y no con maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se puede hacer de ambas maneras, pero yo usé hace poco esa librería con maven y lo veo más sencillo. Simplemente edita el archivo **pom.xml** y le añades las dependencias que necesites. Por ejemplo, así:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
            <version>15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-cql</artifactId>
            <version>15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-geojson</artifactId>
            <version>17.1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Ten en cuenta que Geotools es una librería inmensa, y tal no necesites importar todas las librerías de las que consta. Sólo las necesarias. Aquí puedes ver las librerías para maven de las que consta: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools